# append a string to the beginning of ng-model

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I need to append a string to the ng-model variable.
I'm using the ng-model for filtering. All my elements that i'm searching are starting with the string "template".
I want to add it to the ng-model for not entering "template" in my search input.
I'm using the ng-model for another filtering.

Here is my code:

```
<label>Search By Station: <input ng-model="searchText.screensId"></label>
<label>Search By Template: <input ng-model="searchText.template"></label>
<div data-ng-repeat="msg in messages | filter:searchText">
```

I want to insert the string "template" at the beginning of the 'searchText.template' value.

(like this: "template"+searchText.template)

Comment: If you only want this for the filtering why don't you append the string to `searchText` in the filter? `msg in messages | filter:'template' + searchText`. I might be misunderstanding what you want to achieve though.

Comment: @SzabolcsDézsi - sorry for not giving the full information. I'm using the filter for more filters, so if i'll add like you said it will affect the other searches

Comment: @SzabolcsDézsi - I tried it and its still doesnt work.

Comment: when built in filters aren't adequate it's not hard to create a custom one or use a controller function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add 'tempate' to the beginning of your filter like this:

```
<label>Search By Station: <input ng-model="searchText.screensId"></label>
<label>Search By Template: <input ng-model="searchText.template"></label>
<div data-ng-repeat="msg in messages | filter:('template'+searchText.template)">
```